# Part of proof of contraction mapping theorem, inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, inequality, metric-spaces

The following is part of a proof I am considering for the contraction mapping theorem. I am not having problems with any part of understanding what is going on with the theorem, or what is happening with the proof as a whole, I am just unsure on the following inequality, hence why I have not included more information on the theorem or other parts of the proof.

Consider,

$$\alpha^m(\alpha^{n-m-1}+\alpha^{n-m-2}+...+\alpha^{m})d(x_1,x_0)\le\frac{\alpha^m}{1-\alpha}d(x_1,x_0)$$

where $\alpha<1$.

How is it that $(\alpha^{n-m-1}+\alpha^{n-m-2}+...+\alpha^{m})\le\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$? Can somebody guide me through how to establish this?

Comment: In fact it is a strict $<$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$ is the limit* of the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) $\alpha^{0}+\alpha^1+..$.

As $\alpha^{n-m-1}+\alpha^{n-m-2}+...+\alpha^{m}$ is only part of the series, it is certainly less than the limit of the whole series.

*note that this is only the limit when $|\alpha|<1$ (here's a nice [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence)), which is what we have in the proof of the Contraction Mapping Theorem.

Comment: I see, it is a lot clearer now, cheers!